# SwiftUI, how to remove gray rectangle created by default with a Button?

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

I am running macOS 12.1, Xcode 13.2 and learning SwiftUI (Swift in general). Xcode defaults have been restored, Clean Build Folder applied.

I don't understand how to make this grey rectangle disappear... even when copying examples found on the net, this rectangle still appears. Even if I create a brand new project!

| Preview | Modifiers |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Preview] | [image: Modifiers] |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the default macOS button style. To get rid of it, just attach a custom [`buttonStyle(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/buttonstyle(_:)-66fbx):

```
Button(action: { /* to be completed */ }, label: {
    Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
        .font(.system(size: 24))
        .padding(10)
})
.buttonStyle(.plain) /// here!
```